# Why we can't use both /l and /m keys in shutdown command?

Tags: cmd, key, shutdown

So, /l key makes current user log off immediately. /m key specifies the target computer. Description of /l keys says that we cannot use both these keys. Why?

Comment: Because /l logs off the **current user** on the **current computer**. There's also a LOGOFF command.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good day, Eugenii. So as far as I know you can't use both flags at the same time, because /l only works for current machine, not the remote one.